# Is it because this org-table formula contains double quotes it doesn't work?

Tags: org-table, formula, org-spreadsheet

```
   | Column Name        | Description                               | Comment |
   |--------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------|
   | lyt_form_id        | record id                                 | ")      |
   | lyt_form_app_id    | FK to layout apps                         | ")      |
   | lyt_form_type      | The type name of the form                 | ")      |
   | lyt_form_title     | The form's text name, usually the caption | ")      |
   | lyt_form_notes     | Notes on the form                         | ")      |
   | lyt_form_created   | creation timestamp                        | ")      |
   | lyt_form_updated   | updated timestamp                         | ")      |
   | lyt_form_changelog | Change log                                | ")      |
   #+TBLFM: $3='(concat "COMMENT ON public.layout_forms." $1 " IS " (rc-sq $2) ";")
```

The above table formula doesn't work? It is meant to creaate an SQL comment instruction from the previous two columns.

`rc-sq` is a function that wraps a string in single quotes.

Comment: Not sure what's going on yet, but a workaround is to use `(string 59)` instead of `";"` in the `concat`. I think the `;` is misparsed as the beginning of a [format spec](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html).

Comment: Is it a known bug recognized as a bug by the developers? This ruined my afternoon , but I learned something new.

Comment: No, I will try to submit a bug report and we'll see, But I have a better workaround I think: see the updated answer.

Comment: Bug report is at https://list.orgmode.org/87ply5v1gj.fsf@localhost/T/#t and the maintainer has accepted it, so it should be fixed eventually, but no guarantees about when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in `org-table-eval-formula`: the literal semicolon in the formula is misparsed as a [format spec](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html). The function does [a naive search](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org-table.el#n2454) for a semicolon without taking into account that there might be one "hidden" inside the Lisp expression that is *not* meant as a format specifier.

For the time being, I would suggest that you work around the problem by avoiding the literal semicolon in the formula. One way of doing that is to construct the literal string `";"` at runtime using the `string` function which takes a sequence of characters as arguments and returns a string containing those characters. Normally we would say `(string ?;)` but that also uses a literal semicolon and leads to similar problems, so we use the fact that characters in Emacs Lisp are integers and use the ASCII code for it: `(string 59)`. So the formula becomes:

```
#+TBLFM: $3='(concat "COMMENT ON public.layout_forms." $1 " IS " (rc-sq $2) (string 59))
```

---

EDIT: There is a better workaround:

```
#+TBLFM: $3='(concat "COMMENT ON public.layout_forms." $1 " IS " (rc-sq $2) ";");
```

Adding a semicolon at the end allows the misbehaving regexp to match the *last* semicolon on the line and interpret it as an (empty) format specifier. That leaves the previous semicolon(s) alone.

EDIt 2: A bug report has been submitted and the maintainer has accepted it - see https://list.orgmode.org/87ply5v1gj.fsf@localhost/T/#t

When it gets resolved, I'll update this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort. You've been a great help. Much obliged